# Why is WebGL ANGLE_instanced_arrays extension slow in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I tried to draw about 20,000 objects with the WebGL `ANGLE_instanced_arrays` extension. I'm only draw one 32*32px a box with texture.
In Chrome when I draw 20,000 objects I get 50 fps (I also calculate the fps) but, the frame rate does not look smooth and when number of objects goes up frames comes gets worse.

I tried with Firefox and there it draws very smoothly with 20,000 objects. I even tried drawing 250,000 object it ran a smooth 23 frames per second.

How do I fixed this problem in Chrome?

Comment: I see the same unstable framerate on both Firefox and Chrome on both MacOS and Windows.  https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/4eLmszau/

Comment: Yes I see change it change vert fast 30 and 60. My fps is 50 but some frames are skipping even I use `gl.finish()`.
Is there any stable method for draw thousands objects ? Or do you have any advice what can I do ?